type: ObjectId not displaying custom validation error message
category: {
            type: ObjectId,
            ref: "Category",
            required: [true, "Recipe must belong to a category"],
        },

But if a category isn't selected, the message I get is:
Recipe validation failed: category: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" (type string) at path "category" because of "BSONError"

Why do I not get my custom error message?

Can you share your form/postman payload? It looks like you may be sending an object with "category" : "" which is being taken literally as and empty string for category. If you want the custom error message to trigger then don't send the object with a category key. You will most likely need to modify how you send your form/postman payload then.

@jQueeny Yes I am, it's an option value, can be anything. So what am I supposed to send so that I get the response I want?

Either don't send a key with category in the payload if nothing has been selected for it or on the server check if category is equal to an empty string and if it is just remove that key before using the object in your mongoose query. However, you may want to find out why nothing for category is being sent in the first place. Is that expected behaviour?

@jQueeny Yes it is, it is a valid option meaning "no particular category"

OK but you are saying that category is required in your schema. So your documents won't save without an ObjectId provided for category. If that's what you want to happen i.e. "no Recipe can be saved without having a valid category" then you need to remove the  category key from the object before using it in your mongoose query if  category is empty.
